# Binding the CommandParameter property to a property of another object

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

Probably a noobish question, but here it is:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox x:Name="InsName" Margin="3" Width="180"/>
    <Button Command="cc:MyCommands.AddObject" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=InsName, Path=Text}" >Ok</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Can someone explain why the CommandParameter that is sent when the button is clicked is always NULL? How do I bind a parameter to a property of another element correctly?

Thanks in advance!

PS: bigger portion of the code, just to give some context (all the code works perfectly except the porion I showed above)

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" AllowDrop="{Binding IsGroupNode}" Drop="NodeDrop" DragEnter="NodeOver" DragLeave="NodeLeave">
                    <CheckBox Click="nodeChecked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding IsObjectNode, Converter={StaticResource bool2vis}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding TextColor}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="startDragging">
                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Add Item">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsEnabled="{Binding IsGroupNode}">
                                        <TextBox Name="InsName" Margin="3" Width="180"/>
                                        <Button Command="cc:MyCommands.AddObject" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=InsName, Path=Text}" Height="22" Width="30" IsDefault="True">Ok</Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="cc:MyCommands.RemoveObject" />
                                <Separator />
                                <MenuItem Command="cc:MyCommands.UncheckAll" IsEnabled="{Binding IsGroupNode}" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten about this question, but just in case anyone encounters the same problem, here's the answer:

The problem is that the `binding` is inside a `DataTemplate`, so a direct binding by-name will not work, since the objects are created dynamically at runtime.

A possible solution would be to use a `RelativeSrouce` to navigate to the parent, then use the `Path` to go "back down" to the `TextBox`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsEnabled="{Binding IsGroupNode}">
    <TextBox Name="InsName" Margin="3" Width="180"/>
    <Button Command="cc:MyCommands.AddObject" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}, Path=Children[0].Text}" Height="22" Width="30" IsDefault="True">Ok</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the Output window, if the binding fails, there should be a message there.

Comment: @Master_T Your code seems to work for me (except the command) - is the command  triggering correctly? What is the context of the code (just in XAML, control template, data template etc.)?

Comment: the command fires and routes correctly, it reaches the assigned handler method, but when it does the Parameter is set to null.  I'll edit the first post with a more conprehensive portion of the code.